# Error: value seq is not a member of object slick.dbio.DBIO

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I am writing a web application in play framework. I decided to use slick (FRM) to query in my database (postgre). I am new to slick so I started following slick official document for revision 3.0.0 
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html

As per the documentation, I added dependencies in my build.sbt file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

Everything else is working fine but while writing below line in my Scala IDE. It is showing error that

> value seq is not a member of object slick.dbio.DBIO

```
val setup = DBIO.seq(
// Above line is showing error

(suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create,
.
.
.
)
```

In fact Scala IDE (same as eclipse IDE) isn't detecting any member of object DBIO though when I browse slick api of same version http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.dbio.DBIO$ for object DBIO I am seeing seq as it's member.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I opened a bug with scala ide: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets/1002527

Comment: I tracked the problem to a known bug in the presentation compiler and REPL, and submitted a workaround for the next release of Slick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436661/error-value-seq-is-not-a-member-of-object-slick-dbio-dbio

Comment: @retronym can you fix your link?  You're just linking back here with your work-around.

Comment: Looks like it's this pull-request: https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1224  This will probably hit slick in 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

As anticipated by retronym and Chris Scot, this [problem was fixed](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1224) with the release of Slick 3.1

Comment: Slick 3.1.1: the problem is still here (````TripSaver.scala:20: value Seq is not a member of object slick.dbio.DBIOAction
[error]       val insert = DBIO.Seq(checkpoints map (POI(None, _, None)) map (T.POIs += _))````

Comment: @VitalyIsaev can you check with a lower-case `s` in `DBIO.seq` (not `DBIO.Seq`)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the API for the database you are using:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've got your answer (I'm answering for those that may stumble upon this in the future), but I've resolved this by upgrading to 3.0.0-M1 and using Action.seq() instead of DBIO.seq()

This may also work in 3.0.0, but I'm not sure as I upgraded from Slick 2.x to 3.0.0-M1!